# How do I replace parts of a string?

Tags: python, string

I am very new to python. Could someone explain how I can manipulate a string like this?

This function receives three inputs:

- **complete_fmla:** has a string with digits and symbols but has no  hyphens (`'-'`) nor spaces.
- **partial_fmla:**  has a combination of  hyphens and possibly some digits or symbols, where the digits and symbols that are in it (other than hyphens) are in the same position as in the complete_formula.
- **symbol:** one character

The output  that should be returned is:

- If the symbol is not in the complete formula, or if the symbol is already in the partial formula, the function should return the same formula as the input partial_formula.
- If the symbol is in the complete_formula and not in the partial formula,  the function should return the partial_formula with  the symbol substituting the hyphens in the positions where the symbol is, in  all the occurrences of symbol in the complete_formula.

Basically, I'm working with the definition:

```
def generate_next_fmla (complete_fmla, partial_fmla, symbol):
```

Do I turn them into lists? and then append? 
Also, should I find out the index number for the symbol in the `complete_fmla` so that I know where to append it in the string with hyphens??

Comment: re.sub would probably help ...

Comment: Rather than store your data in strings, I suggest storing your data in lists.  When you print them out, you can join them together.  Unlike strings, lists are *mutable*, meaning you can change the **object** that the variable is pointing to.  This way, you can create a function that prints the object as a string *only* when you need it printed.  (if you want to print every iteration, that's fine, if you want to only print at the end, that's fine too).

Answer (score 1):

it's a simple onliner function

```
def generate_next_fmla(base, filt, char):
    return ''.join( c if c==char else filt[idx] for idx,c in enumerate(base)  )
```

the core idea is the if else clause:

```
c if c==char else filt[idx]
```

which, given the each character and its position in the original string, put it in the new string if is equal to the selected character, otherway place the value from the filter string

written in a more verbose way, look like the following:

```
def generate_next_fmla (complete_fmla, partial_fmla, symbol):
    chars = ""
    for idx in range(len(complete_fmla)):
        c = complete_fmla[idx]
        if c==symbol:
            chars = chars + c
        else:
            chars = chars + partial_fmla[idx] 
    return chars
```

this is the same function written in a more on several lines (it is actually way less efficient, as the sun of string is a bad habit)

Comment: `complete_fmla` (base) and `partial_fmla` (filt) doesn't appear to have the same lenght in the question - `filt[idx*2]` should cover the case of 2x the lenght of base...

Comment: Weel, actually he specified that the characters in the partial_fmla list are in the same position as the original one. Given tha extra spaces and the strange string delimiter, it seems like it's copied from a exercise, isn't it? :(

Comment: oh,, i edited the example in question to match this specification (just before OP deleted the example :()

Comment: I am afraid that this answer is beyond what I can understand. I am not looking for the quickest answer. I just need help understanding what to do in the SIMPLEST way. Thank you so much!

Comment: oh, you are missing one condition in your code i believe - `if c==char and filt[idx]=='-'`

Comment: I don't think such a condition is necessary..given that partial_fmla is a string where the present char are in the same place as in the original string (as stated by the question) it's implicit that if the character has already been filtered it will just replace with the same char...so no harm done

Answer (score 0):

Greetings you can try to use regular expressions, I think they will help you a lot for what you want to achieve,  here you have the [link](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Some exemples within that documentation:

```
>>> import re
>>> m = re.search('(?<=abc)def', 'abcdef')
>>> m.group(0)
'def'
```

Answer (score 0):

No doubt there are edge cases that you'll need to add, but this should work for the simple case:

```
def generate_next_fmla (complete_fmla, partial_fmla, symbol):
    result = partial_fmla.strip().split(' ')[:] 
    for index, c in enumerate(complete_fmla):
        if c == symbol:
            result[index] = c
    return "".join(result)
```

It converts to a list and back again to make changing it easier.

EDIT: I now realise this is similar to EnricoGiampieri's answer, but with lists.

Answer (score 0):

as a beginner to python, probably the best approach to start is to map your requirements 1:1 to your code - i hope following is as self-explanatory as possible:

```
def generate_next_fmla (complete_fmla, partial_fmla, symbol):
    # test that complete_fmla does not contain '-'
    if '-' in complete_fmla:
        raise ValueError("comple_fmla contains '-'")
    # delete all spaces from partial_fmla if needed (this need was suggested
    # in the original question with some examples that contained spaces)
    partial_fmla = partial_fmla.replace(' ', '')
    # test if it is possible to test the "same positions" from both strings
    if len(complete_fmla) != len(partial_fmla):
        raise ValueError("complete_fmla does not have the same lenght as partial_fmla")
    # add other input checking as needed ...

    if symbol not in complete_fmla or symbol in partial_fmla:
        return partial_fmla

    # partial_fmla[i] = symbol wouldn't work in python
    # because strings are immutable, but it is possible to do this:
    # partial_fmla = partial_fmla[:i] + symbol + partial_fmla[i+1:]
    # and another approach is to start with an empty string
    result = ''
    for i in range(len(partial_fmla)):
        # for every character position in the formulas
        # if there is '-' in this position in the partial formula
        # and the symbol in this position in the complete formula
        if partial_fmla[i] == '-' and complete_fmla[i] == symbol:
            # then append the symbol to the result
            result += symbol
        else:
            # otherwise use the character from this positon in the partial formula
            result += partial_fmla[i]
    return result

print(generate_next_fmla ('abcdeeaa', '--------', 'd')) # ‘---d----’
print(generate_next_fmla ('abcdeeaa', '- - - x - - - - ', 'e')) # ‘---xee--’
print(generate_next_fmla ('abcdeeaa', 'x-------', 'a')) # ‘x-----aa’
print(generate_next_fmla ('abcdeeaa', 'x-----', 'a'))   # Exception
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this code:

```
lst_fmla = []
def generate_next_fmla(s_str, fmla, c_char):
    i = 0
    for s in s_str:
        if c_char is s: lst_fmla.append(c_char)
        elif fmla[i] != '-': lst_fmla.append(fmla[i])
        else: lst_fmla.append('-')
        i = i + 1
    print(''.join(lst_fmla))
generate_next_fmla('abcdeeaa', '---d----', 'e')
```

If for example your second argument in the function generate_next_fmla is like this '----d---', which 'd' would be the same index of the third argument('e'), it will be replaced with 'e'.